# Mysql if condition for two columns

Tags: mysql

I want to check the following condition in MYSQL. Please help me to find the solution for the below condition

Condition :

```
If(fld_intime == null)
{
    'InMiss' 
}
else if(fld_outtime == null)
{
   'Outmiss'
}
else 
{
    'Present'
}
```

How can i create this using select statement..

Comment: where is `InMiss`, `OutMiss`, `Present` be outputted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you looking  for this:

```
select case when fld_intime is null 
            then 'InMiss'
            when fld_outtime  is null 
            then 'Outmiss'
            else 'Present'
       end as Remarks
from your_table
```

Comment: I want to create a new column named "Remarks" and add the remarks for each column like this 'Inmiss' or 'Present or outmiss

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT IF(fld_intime IS NULL, 'InMiss', IF(fld_outtime IS NULL, 'Outmiss', 'Present'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN fld_intime is null THEN 'InMiss'
        WHEN fld_outtime is null THEN 'OutMiss'
        ELSE 'Present'
    END AS fld_status  from yourtable
```

Answer (score 0):

writing sql examplee.. Use [Case](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html) statement in your where query

```
select 
      case when fld_intime is null then 'InMiss' 
           when fld_outtime is null then 'Outmiss' 
      else 'Present' end
from yourTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
Select 
 CASE

 WHEN fld_inTime is null
  THEN 'InMiss' 
WHEN fld_outTime is null
THEN 'outMiss' 
ELSE
'Present'
END
from table
```